# Sequence Numbering in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have an table (always ordered by ID ascending) with 5 records as such :

```
ID  Sequence
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
8   3
9   3
```

And the desired output is :

```
ID  Sequence
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   6
8   4
9   5
```

Comment: How do you calculate that `ID = 8` should have `Sequence = 4` (and so on)?

Comment: @martin "if ID is even and sequence is odd then add 1 else add 2, for id greater than 3?" :)

Comment: But the ID will vary for each of scenario.  

The exact scenario is, i have predefined set of records that get populated from a defined template table.  

And during the process, user inputs ad-hoc records that gets inserted based on record status (for example the ad-hoc record should be inserted after the last in-progress status record)  

In this case, it is the 3rd record as the 4th record is in open state.

Twice the user added ad-hoc task and the ID for these records are 8 and 9.

Comment: First ad-hoc record added is copy of the 3rd record.  Similarly the second time added ad-hoc record is also copy of the 3rd record as both have to be added last to the in-progress record which is the 3rd one.

I think, there is correction in the above sequencing number, always the recent ad-hoc record should have sequence number as 3+1.  That means ID=8 should be 5 and ID=9 should be 4 and ID=4 should be 6.

Let me know if you have any questions.  Thank you for quick reply.

Comment: The update has to go with one single query for each scenario.

Comment: Offtopic, but at first one tells that "table with 5 records" and then presents 6 records - off by one error? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in one step:

```
update t
    set sequence = v.sequence
    from t join
         (values (4, 6), (8, 4), (9, 5)
         ) v(id, sequence)
         on t.id = v.id;
```

If you have to do many of these updates, then separate calls to `update` incur extra overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it did help in finding a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 3 direct updates to me, no point over complicating it:

```
UPDATE table SET sequence = 6 WHERE id = 4 
UPDATE table SET sequence = 4 WHERE id = 8
UPDATE table SET sequence = 5 WHERE id = 9
```